# Scales or real-world ideals of deliberative democracy?

Tags: political-theory

I only had a superficial contact with the literature on [deliberative democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deliberative_democracy)... but it seems to me it's extremely theory-laden.

What I'd like to know if there have been empirical proposals to gauge how deliberative a democracy is. Or lacking that, are there even some real-world [close to] ideals of deliberative democracy being discussed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citations in [this brief review](https://www.amacad.org/publication/twelve-key-findings-deliberative-democracy-research) are somewhat on point. A [deliberative democracy index](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-relationships-between-Deliberative-Democracy-Index-the-Electoral-Democracy-Index_fig1_281289495) chart illustrates this in different countries. Background on the index is [here](https://www.v-dem.net/en/). The 2018 country deliberative democracy scores with detailed subcomponents appear at [pages 91-93](https://www.v-dem.net/media/filer_public/68/51/685150f0-47e1-4d03-97bc-45609c3f158d/v-dem_annual_dem_report_2018.pdf) (internal pagination) in the V-Dem annual report. Norway is number 1. The USA ranks 94th and lower on all sub-scores except having an engaged society.

While I can't think of any national government that uses this approach in a consistent way, probably the closest practical example is the way that the Society of Friends (a.k.a. Quakers) [organize their meetings and governance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monthly_meeting). This spilled over, to some extent, into the early days of [town meetings in New England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_meeting).

It was intended to be a major part of the operations of upper houses of bicameral legislatures, like the U.S. Senate and the House of Lords and Canadian Senate, but this has increasingly ceased to be how those chambers operate.